# WEKA Weighted Average Question Mark

Tags: weka

According to the output by WEKA below, some of the Weighted Avg. has values but the other has a question mark. For TP Rate, the Weighted Avg. is calculated even though there are two question marks at `STM_TA` and `UM_KRTN` rows. But, it not calculated for Precision, F-Measure and MCC.

```
=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.714    0.000    1.000      0.714    0.833      0.845    1.000     1.000     MEA0072
                 0.818    0.001    0.818      0.818    0.818      0.817    0.999     0.913     MEA0095
                 0.885    0.001    0.958      0.885    0.920      0.920    1.000     0.983     MEA1061
                 1.000    0.001    0.981      1.000    0.990      0.990    1.000     0.999     MEA2087
                 0.846    0.001    0.846      0.846    0.846      0.845    1.000     0.965     MEA2098
                 0.938    0.001    0.938      0.938    0.938      0.937    1.000     0.968     MEA2099
                 0.971    0.001    0.943      0.971    0.957      0.956    0.999     0.973     MEB0079
                 0.917    0.000    1.000      0.917    0.957      0.957    1.000     1.000     MEE0075
                 1.000    0.001    0.967      1.000    0.983      0.983    1.000     1.000     MFT0001
                 0.930    0.001    0.976      0.930    0.952      0.952    0.999     0.967     MFT0002
                 1.000    0.000    1.000      1.000    1.000      1.000    1.000     1.000     MFT0003
                 1.000    0.000    1.000      1.000    1.000      1.000    1.000     1.000     MFT1001
                 0.944    0.002    0.850      0.944    0.895      0.895    1.000     0.986     MFT1002
                 1.000    0.000    1.000      1.000    1.000      1.000    1.000     1.000     MFT1003
                 1.000    0.001    0.975      1.000    0.987      0.987    1.000     0.999     MFT2001
                 1.000    0.000    1.000      1.000    1.000      1.000    1.000     1.000     MRA1002
                 1.000    0.000    1.000      1.000    1.000      1.000    1.000     1.000     MRA2125
                 1.000    0.001    0.984      1.000    0.992      0.992    1.000     1.000     MRA2127
                 ?        0.000    ?          ?        ?          ?        ?         ?         STM_TA
                 0.786    0.051    0.793      0.786    0.790      0.737    0.948     0.818     STM_TL
                 0.547    0.106    0.553      0.547    0.550      0.443    0.848     0.588     STM_TT
                 0.000    0.000    ?          0.000    ?          ?        0.894     0.064     STM_X
                 0.547    0.008    0.806      0.547    0.652      0.649    0.978     0.762     UM_KK
                 0.864    0.082    0.787      0.864    0.824      0.760    0.941     0.815     UM_KRK
                 ?        0.000    ?          ?        ?          ?        ?         ?         UM_KRTN
Weighted Avg.    0.797    0.053    ?          0.797    ?          ?        0.943     0.816     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   <-- classified as
   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   a = MEA0072
   0   9   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   b = MEA0095
   0   0  23   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   c = MEA1061
   0   0   0  51   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   d = MEA2087
   0   2   0   0  11   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   e = MEA2098
   0   0   0   0   1  15   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   f = MEA2099
   0   0   0   0   0   0  33   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   g = MEB0079
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  11   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   h = MEE0075
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  29   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   i = MFT0001
   0   0   0   1   0   0   2   0   0  40   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   j = MFT0002
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  23   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   k = MFT0003
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  45   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   l = MFT1001
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  17   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   m = MFT1002
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  16   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   n = MFT1003
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  39   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   o = MFT2001
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  55   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   p = MRA1002
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  58   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   q = MRA2125
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  61   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   r = MRA2127
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   s = STM_TA
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 302  70   0   2  10   0 |   t = STM_TL
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  51 204   0  12 106   0 |   u = STM_TT
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0   0   1   0 |   v = STM_X
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3  45   0  58   0   0 |   w = UM_KK
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  25  43   0   0 433   0 |   x = UM_KRK
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 |   y = UM_KRTN
```

I had searched through the internet, but there is no answer for the question mark at Weighted Avg. I hope anyone could help me to explain why some of them are calculated but not others?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The '?' is used in Weka instead of NaN (not a number) due to due to zero denominator. E.g. in your case, the precision for class STM_X is ‘?’ that there are no instances assigned to the class, thus denominator is zero. Furthermore, STM_TA and UM_KRTN have no samples at all.

When '?' symbols appear in the output, the specific class may have not enough samples or none of the samples can be assigned to the class. In your case, two classes have no samples at all, thus provides ‘?’ for all metrics. In the case presented, the weighted average for TP, FP, Recall, ROC and PRC has value although there ‘?’ in its columns.
Note that, the class STM_TA and UM_KRTN has ‘?’ for all metrics except FP (because there is no false positive due to no samples at all), thus ‘?’ in the column can be just 0 and weighted average can be calculated. However, for STM_X, there are 8 samples but none of the samples can be assigned correctly to class, therefore NaN or ‘?’ and weighted average could not be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

The ? (undetermined) values are propagating. Note in the lines above you have some values that are also ?.  Note you have some classes that no instances were classified in.

Comment: Thank you. But, why the ? only at several metrics. If we see, TP Rate has weighted value even though it has some values above it with ? too but Precision hasn't.